# Customize vim cursor style under Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I want to customize the vim cursor to be a blinking rectangle block. I tried [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor) and [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes) and many other similar stuffs after some searches, but none of them works as expected.

Currently my cursor is an non-blinking underline in grey (i.e. the underline below character "e" in the last line below), which is pretty hard to recognize.

[image: underline cursor]

When the cursor is over a parenthesis character, it becomes a block. (Actually I believe this is a change in background color) What I want is to have this block all the time, and blinking.

[image: block cursor]

I have nothing related to cursor style in my .vimrc file. I am using Mac OS X 10.9, Terminal Version 2.4 (326), and oh-my-zsh.  In Terminal settings, I use Pro theme and set cursor to underline. I can change this to block so the cursor in vim changes as well, but I need the underline cursor in a normal Terminal.

[image: terminal settings]

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one in your `.vimrc`:

```
let &t_SI="\033[4 q" " start insert mode
let &t_EI="\033[1 q" " end insert mode
```

This will set under line for inset mode and block for normal.
More details: http://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECSCUSR

Also it's possible to play with this command in terminal, where is X can be 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.

```
printf '\033[X q'
```

Comment: The `\033` escape character was the crux for me. The other suggestions using `\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>` didn't work on OSX Terminal.app with Tmux, zsh, vim.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try adding this to your vimrc:

```
if exists('$TMUX')
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7\<Esc>\\"
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7\<Esc>\\"
else
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
endif
```

That should provide the correct escape sequences for tmux or iTerm.

I also found [this](https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim) plugin that auto changes the cursor based on the current mode.

Comment: It doesn't work.  I use neither tmux nor iTerm.  I am using the Terminal.app provided by Mac OS X and zsh.

Comment: Found this post and am using tmux - works great thanks!